# GROUP BY in JOIN'ed result set in MS-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a working query for orderlines that include a specific range of items, then I join in the order information.

```
SELECT Orders.*, Orderp.*
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN
    Orderp ON Orderp.StoreID = Orders.StoreID 
  AND 
    Orderp.[Date] = Orders.[Date] 
  AND 
    Orderp.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
WHERE
    (Orders.ItemType = 2)
  AND 
    (Orders.ItemNumberOnMenu IN (68, 69, 70, 71, 72)) 
  AND 
    (Orders.[Date] > '2013/01/01')
```

If I add `GROUP BY Orderp.Telephone` at the end of the above query, I get the following error.[image]

Any ideas how to group on the phone number of the customer?

Comment: You have to order by ALL of the columns in talbe `Orders` and `Orderp`, if you select all of the data from these tables.

Comment: maybe group by Orderp.Telephone and then Orders.OrdersID?

Comment: Please provide field info for tables. You can't use GROUP BY clause with a * being selected. You must specify a list of fields in the SELECT part and the columns present in the SELECT clause must be a part of the GROUP BY clause unless you are using an aggregate.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I think you mean `Group By` you can `Order by` any number of columns.

Comment: Clearly I'm not used to MSSQL :) Normally work with MySQL as you might have guessed. I have accepted the answer from @Zane . I stripped out the wildcards and added the selected fields to the GROUP BY - and it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets try our best to straighten this out for you.

You are using a `GROUP BY` which is usually accompanied by an aggregate function. For example if I want the average sales for my products I would use. [GroupBy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

```
SELECT
    AVG(Sales),
    ProductID
FROM MostGenericTable
GROUP BY ProductID
```

There now that will show me the average sales for each `ProductID`.

This is why your query doesn't work. You are grouping by just one column and performing no aggregation on the others.

The second problem you have with your query is it's lazy. Type in the columns that you wish to receive. Don't use `SELECT *` the reasons are numerous and a simple google search will give you numerous results. In your specific example it's giving you problems because you don't even know which columns to `Group By`.

Since you are using `Group By` in this manner it's possible you're actually looking for `ORDER BY` which will sort the row set that is returned. [OrderBy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

```
SELECT 
    Orders.*, 
    Orderp.*
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Orderp 
ON Orderp.StoreID = Orders.StoreID 
  AND Orderp.[Date] = Orders.[Date] 
  AND Orderp.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
WHERE (Orders.ItemType = 2)
  AND (Orders.ItemNumberOnMenu IN (68, 69, 70, 71, 72)) 
  AND (Orders.[Date] > '2013/01/01')
ORDER BY Orderp.Telephone
```

Hopefully that explanation helps you to not make these mistakes in the future.

Comment: Clearly I'm not used to MSSQL :) Normally work with MySQL as you might have guessed. I have accepted the answer from @Zane -Thanks. I stripped out the wildcards and added the selected fields to the GROUP BY - and it works!

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to `GROUP BY` Telephone, you either need an aggregate for every other field, or to group on them also:

```
SELECT MAX(Orders.col1) col1
     , MAX(Orders.col2) col2
     , Orderp.Telephone
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Orderp 
  ON Orderp.StoreID = Orders.StoreID 
   AND    Orderp.[Date] = Orders.[Date] 
   AND    Orderp.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
WHERE   (Orders.ItemType = 2)
  AND   (Orders.ItemNumberOnMenu IN (68, 69, 70, 71, 72)) 
  AND   (Orders.[Date] > '2013/01/01')
GROUP BY Orderp.Telephone
```

OR:

```
SELECT Orders.col1
     , Orders.col2
     , Orderp.Telephone
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Orderp 
  ON Orderp.StoreID = Orders.StoreID 
   AND    Orderp.[Date] = Orders.[Date] 
   AND    Orderp.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
WHERE   (Orders.ItemType = 2)
  AND   (Orders.ItemNumberOnMenu IN (68, 69, 70, 71, 72)) 
  AND   (Orders.[Date] > '2013/01/01')
GROUP BY Orders.col1
     , Orders.col2
     , Orderp.Telephone
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike MySQL , if a column is present in SELECT list but absent in GROUP BY clause or not used by aggregate function eg MAX , SUM ..etc will result in query throwing error as shown above.

To remove duplicates based on particular field which if I Understand you correctly is `Orderp.Telephone` , you can use ranking functions on partitions like `rownumber , rank , dense_rank` . ( Sql server 2005+)

```
Select * From
( SELECT Orders.col1, Orders.col2,Orders.col3,Orderp.col1, Orderp.2,
       Row_number() Over (partition by Orderp.Telephone order by    
  Orderp.Storeid) as rownum
  FROM Orders  INNER JOIN
    Orderp ON Orderp.StoreID = Orders.StoreID 
  AND 
    Orderp.[Date] = Orders.[Date] 
  AND 
    Orderp.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
WHERE
    (Orders.ItemType = 2)
  AND 
    (Orders.ItemNumberOnMenu IN (68, 69, 70, 71, 72)) 
  AND 
    (Orders.[Date] > '2013/01/01')
) z
WHERE rownum =1
```